# Javascript object values returning as [object,object]

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object like the following:

```
var Numeric_values = {
US:  {01: "202-555-0151", 02: "202-555-0167", 03: "202-555-0150"},
CAD: {01: "613-555-0144", 02: "613-555-0192", 03:"613-555-0151"},
AUS: {01: "1900 654 321"}
};
```

I am attempting to access all of the values of this object and listing them out as a string like this:

```
"202-555-0151","202-555-0167", "202-555-0150"
"613-555-0144", "613-555-0192","613-555-0151"
"1900 654 321"
```

I have so far attempted to use Object.values(Numeric_Values) and

```
for (let key in Numeric_values){
      console.log(Numeric_values[key]);
  }
```

and these always return as [object,object], how can i fix this?

Comment: And how is `textOut()` defined? That's what you should have showed in your attempt.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it out. For the purpose of this it functionally works as console.log().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print/access them via [**`Object.values`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [**`Array.forEach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var data = {
  US: {
    01: "202-555-0151",
    02: "202-555-0167",
    03: "202-555-0150"
  },
  CAD: {
    01: "613-555-0144",
    02: "613-555-0192",
    03: "613-555-0151"
  },
  AUS: {
    01: "1900 654 321"
  }
};

Object.values(data).forEach(x => console.log(...Object.values(x)))
```

You could also recursively get the values like so:

```js
var data = {
  US: {
    01: "202-555-0151",
    02: "202-555-0167",
    03: "202-555-0150"
  },
  CAD: {
    01: "613-555-0144",
    02: "613-555-0192",
    03: "613-555-0151"
  },
  AUS: {
    01: "1900 654 321"
  }
};

const flatten = (obj, a = []) => Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((r, c) => (typeof c == 'object' ? flatten(c, a) : r.push(c), r), a)

console.log(...flatten(data))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that is exactly what i needed, how does .map work differently from what i have been doing though?

Comment: You don't need `map` since you don't intend to create a new array. `forEach` is more appropriate.

Comment: You can use forEach

Comment: `forEach` it is. Thanks.